# Heat equation, analytic solution to square with high heat in center and low heat along edges.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, heat-equation

Being inspired by some other question of the Heat equation in 2 spatial dimensions:
$$\Delta T + \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = 0\\\left(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}\right)T +  \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=0$$

I made a small experiment with the following setup:

1. A rectangular area,
2. heat source as a point in the middle (constant high temperature)
3. the edges have a constant low temperature,
4. the starting temperature for everything in between is the same as the rectangular border.

---

How can I analytically derive the solution that this will have? I have been thinking about Fourier analysis where I think is common to solve problems like this, but it was such a long time I don't remember it all.

I am mostly curious to see if I can compare to / verify my home built numerical scheme which does find a solution on a discrete grid.

Comment: Two dimensional Fourier Series shoulld do it with an assumed separable solution of the form A(x)B(y)C(t). The method is long and I doubt anyone will want to go through it all. Look up any engineering maths or maths for science book. If you only want to get a feel for the solution it might be easier to consider a disc rather than a rectangle and assume a spherically symmetric solution of the form A(r)B(t).

Comment: Yes I know, however I am rather mobile and therefore don't have access to my old books.

Comment: Expand the initial temperature $T(x,y,0)$ in a Fourier series compatible with the boundary conditions (here assuming the box is $[0,2\pi]^2$):
$$T(x,y,t=0) = \sum_{n,m} a_{nm}(t=0) \sin(nx)\sin(mx)$$ 
Now take the ansatz above for the full solution and insert into the PDE and compare to get $a_{nm}'(t) = -(n^2+m^2)a_{nm}$. The solution is $a_{nm}(t) = a_{nm}(t=0) e^{-(n^2+m^2)t}$. This gives you an expression for the solution in terms of a series (I'm using you meant $\Delta T = T_t$ as the PDE; otherwise $t\to -t$ gives you your equation). Also assuming $T=0$ at the boundary.